# Why does the compiler completely ignore the first for loop then goes to the 2nd loop?

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

I've been trying to make something that can encrypt messages. The problem I have is that my idea won't work. I have 2 different sets of the alphabet `char lettr_set1[]` and `char lettr_set2[]`. `lettr_set1` would have the first half of the alphabet while `lettr_set2` have the second half. I would like to allow the user to input an encryption code, so to speak. I would like for the letter to swap letters with its corresponding letter in the other set so to speak. Like if the letter "a" is available in the user's input, it should be swapped to "n", if the letter "b" is available in the user's input, it should be swapped to "o" and so on. Before all of this, an "encryption code" is required from the user. This encryption could should then be added to each individual letter.

For example, if the encryption code is 2, and the user's input has the letter "n", the letter "n" should now be c.

The output that I'm getting is just the encryption code being added to the initial user input instead of the swapped.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>


    int main (void)
    {
     char lettr_set1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'};
     char lettr_set2[] = {'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
     
     int number = get_int("Encryption code: ");
     
     if (number > 9)
     {
         printf("Error: 1 \nThis number is too big and might result in some letters not being found.\n");
        return 1;
     }
     
     string s = get_string("Message to encrypt: ");
     printf("Output: ");
    
    
     int n = strlen(s);
     
     if (strlen(s) < 8)
        {
           printf(" Error: 2 \n Your message is too short so an encrypted message can't be generated. \n");
           return 2;  
        }
    
     for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
       {
           
        if (s[i] == lettr_set2[i])
        {
           printf("%c", s[i] - 13);
        }
    
        if (s[i] == lettr_set1[i])
        {
           printf("%c", s[i] + 13);
        }
       }
    
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
       
        printf("%c", s[i] + number);
     
       }
     
     printf("\n");
    
    }
```

Comment: how do you know that its compiler?

Comment: If the test `s[i] == lettr_set2[i]` is never true, and `[i] == lettr_set1[i]` is never true, there is nothing to execute. Perhaps use `tolower(s[i])` to ensure a case match and check that the character `!ispunct()` and `!isdigit()`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Can you give an example?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , and also consider learning how to use a debugger. If the flow of execution *seems* not to reach a certain point, that is an inference you are drawing based on the output; but maybe the output looks that way for a different reason. The way to be sure is to use tools that explicitly step through the code and show you what happens, when.

Comment: Why 12 in  `i < 12`?   `i < n` makes more sense.

Comment: `string s = get_string(` - none of this is built in to C. I am going to **guess** that you are following the cs50 course, which uses its own libraries that provide these definitions. You should, if so: a) *tell us this*; b) use the [cs50] tag for your question; c) make sure that your code sample shows the appropriate `#include` lines.

Comment: maybe your input didn't have any matching characters?  You only test for `a` in first position, `b` in second position, etc.   I guess you actually wanted to test for `a` in any position (which currently you don't do)

Comment: where is `get_int` function?

Comment: `if (s[i] == lettr_set2[i])` Try to give me an example of what `s` and `lettr_set` look like, and what `i` is equal to, in order to make this happen. Try to think carefully about what happens each time through the loop. Try to explain the overall purpose of the loop. I think you will be able to see for yourself that the loop cannot possibly do what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Just consider: You input "hello". Now, is `h` either `a` or `n` ? Nope, so nothing. Is `e` either `b` or `o` ? Nope, so.. nothing, etc. You're missing an outer nesting level, and it should be based on the string length, not some magic number 12.

Comment: @CEPB I get suspended if I delete this question.

Comment: @M.M Is there a function currently that can do this?

Comment: @Anique suspended from a job? From SO you will not get suspended!!!!

Comment: @CEPB I wouldn't be able to post any questions for a specific amount of time.

Comment: @Anique ok than, look at my answer, start from there

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `get_string()` is part of the CS50 project from Harvard. It simply allocates for and inputs a string -- it's fine. (note the `#include <cs50.h>`). See [This is CS50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/2021/spring/)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with CS50, and guessed that it was being used. The `#include` wasn't there when I made the original comment, which is why I asked to make sure that I had correctly guessed about it.

Comment: "I get suspended [from Stack Overflow] if I delete this question." Right; judging by your previous questions, what you don't seem to have understood is that *Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation*, and is not a place to get tutoring or mentoring. Please try talking to your instructor(s) or their assistant(s) first, and failing that, try a proper forum website such as https://reddit.com/r/learnprogramming (but be sure to read their rules and FAQ first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loops & decision tree had to be sth like below:

```
// encryption "number" defined before and initialized via input
int i = 0;

while s[i] { // terminates when '\0' is reached
    int found = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
        if (s[i] == lettr_set1[j]) {
            printf("%c", lettr_set2[(j + number) % 13]);
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            if (s[i] == lettr_set2[j]) {
                printf("%c", lettr_set1[(j - number) % 13]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    i++;
}
```